# Pentaho Text Input multiple languages English and Japanese Characters Loaded into MSSQL data table separate columns

Tags: javascript, regex, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am trying to load a SQL table with a text file. I am using the Text File Input Step. All but one column may contain Japanese characters(Comment). How can I pass all English text and Japanese text as readable characters?
Is there a regex or Java Script code that will pass all of these characters or some other step that Pentaho offers? I prefer not to alter the server if possible.

[image: Sample Data]

I am at a loss.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it is a simple as setting the encoding to Shift_JS

[image: Pentaho soln.]